# Why isn't the Pattern attribute working for type="date"?

Tags: html, css

```
<form action="phph.php">
    <input type="date" name="date" pattern="(06){1}[- /.](30){1}[- /.](1989){1}">
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my pattern code, but it isn't working for the date. I am using Chrome, and my date format is mm/dd/yyyy.

Is my pattern code wrong, or is it that, pattern doesn't apply for type="date"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date does not support `pattern` attribute. Internally it uses yyyy-mm-dd format, but it shows date formatted to user locale.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" class="datepicker" name="date" value="" />
```